# DestinationRule is not applied on ServiceEntry

Tags: kubernetes, istio

When I specify host in ServiceEntry and DestinationRule as httpbin, DestinationRule doesn't work. But it works, if I added suffix, i.e. httpbin.se.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - httpbin # don't work
#    - httpbin.se # work
  ports:
    - number: 443
      name: http-443
      protocol: HTTP
    - number: 80
      name: http-80
      protocol: HTTP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
  addresses:
    - "34.235.36.14"
  endpoints:
    - address: "34.235.36.14"
      ports:
        http-443: 443
        http-80: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: httpbin # don't work.
# host: httpbin.se # work
  trafficPolicy:
    portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 443
        tls:
          mode: SIMPLE
```

Maybe I missed some documentation, can't be sure.

Comment: Is your httpbin service deployed in `default` or `se` namespace? If it's in `se` namespace and  you have destination rule and service entry in default namespace then short name `httpbin` resolves to `httpbin.default` and it's not gonna work, unless you use `httpbin.se` or change the service entry and destination rule namespace to `se`.

Comment: What are you trying to connect to, both inside and outside the cluster?  What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @Jakub, all done in default namespace, suffix doesn't matter. Suffix could be any valid domain name.

Comment: @David Maze, there is no error. Simply tls block is not applied, so traffic goes to http, when must to https.

Comment: Do you have a service called httpbin deployed in your cluster? There is a note in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/#ServiceEntry) `NOTE 2: If the hostname matches with the name of a service from another service registry such as Kubernetes that also supplies its own set of endpoints, the ServiceEntry will be treated as a decorator of the existing Kubernetes service.`

Comment: @Jakub, no, I don't.

Comment: What is your istio version? How do you test if it works, with curl?